# Is it possible to handle file management in a Sharepoint Online team site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I've been tasked with implementing a full-blown SharePoint website using SharePoint Online, but I am still quite new and I need some help.

The design team has sent us a layout completely different than what Sharepoint offers in its templates. We're also supposed to display files using categories, though we haven't found anything related to file category/hierarchy management in SharePoint Online's interface.
What I'd like to do is to display the files myself (with my own HTML/CSS) in a SharePoint Online team site. I've been unable to find any documentation on how to do so using SharePoint online - the only documentation I seem to find is for SharePoint 2013.

Is there any documentation on how to do that ? Is it even possible to do such a thing with a team site on SharePoint Online ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? Is this an external website like www.mycompany.com or an internal site like portal.mycompany.com? Why use html/css instead of the standard SharePoint functionality?

Comment: It's an internal website: we're making an Intranet for another company. They requested that we work with Sharepoint, but our designers sent us a layout completely different than what Sharepoint offers in its templates. We're also supposed to display files using categories, though we haven't found anything related to file category/hierarchy management in Sharepoint Online's interface.

Comment: Your company should not have taken a SharePoint job without having SharePoint experience, this will not turn out well. As below, you are going to need to edit the master pages (use SharePoint designer) and for the file systems, look at managed metadata (if they have enterprise SharePoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you activate the site collection feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" you enable the following: *Provides centralized libraries, content types, **master pages and page layouts** and enables page scheduling and other publishing functionality for a site collection*.

With this enabled, you can copy an existing master page and add your own references to CSS and JavaScript files. You will also have the option to copy and create your own Page Layout HTML.

Reference: [Enable or disable Site Collection Features](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-HA102772720.aspx)